# How to display the expiration time of django-cookie?

Tags: django, cookies

In my `getCookie` function, I'd like to display the name AND the expiration-time of given cookie, but all I've been able to archive is the name of it, as a string.

The cookie is set, and expires as expected, I'd just like to show the remaining time of it, in a simple way.

```
def setCookie(request):
    cook = HttpResponseRedirect('/getCookie/')
    cook.set_cookie('theCookie', value='Dough', max_age=15)

    return cook

def getCookie(request):
    s=""
    if request.COOKIES.has_key('theCookie'):
        s += request.COOKIES['theCookie']
        #s += request.COOKIES['theCookie'].expires..? HERE?

    else:
        s="Sorry, your cookie has expired"
    return HttpResponse(s)
```

Comment: I don't think django can provide such thing. In django cookies are just name, value pair.

Comment: Bad news, any way to access it via client-side scripts, perhaps?

Comment: yes in javascript you can get the expiry time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`request.COOKIES` only contains the key/value mapping of the parsed cookies. However `request.META['HTTP_COOKIE']` contains the raw cookie string which can be parsed by the Python  `cookie.SimpleCookie` class to get the `max-age` http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html

Comment: Ah, great. Thanks! I kinda 'solved' it by appending a datetime.now()-string to the value of the cookie, and then slicing it at print. Not THE way to go, eh.

Answer (score 6):

Expire time of a cookie can be foiund like this:

```
import Cookie
val = request.META['HTTP_COOKIE']
c = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
c.load(val)
c['cookie-name'].keys()
... 
comment,domain,secure,expires,max-age,version,path,httponly

expires = c['cookie-name']['expires']
```

Comment: Curiously enough, i ran in to a use case where i might need this again. 5½ years later. Thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps this works with some browsers, but current Safari does not include expiration dates with HTTP_COOKIE data.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6 and had to change the import to: `from http.cookies import SimpleCookie` and then `c = SimpleCookie()`

Answer (score -5):

Short answer: it can't be done.

Comment: as you can see, that statement is always falsified by the first person to do it :^P

Answer (score -6):

Try get_expiry_age:

```
request.COOKIES['theCookie'].get_expiry_age()
```

Comment: Nah, 'request.COOKIES['theCookie']' only returns a string.

'str' object has no attribute 'get_expiry_age'

Comment: Are you talking about Cookies here, or do you really mean session?

Comment: Not sure i know the difference, please explain.