# Reading cookie expiration date in django

Tags: python, django, cookies

When I run

```
request.COOKIES.get(key)
```

I get the cookie value.

How do I get the cookie expiration date?

(get_signed_cookie() throws me *** BadSignature: No ":" found in value error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display the expiration time of django-cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817992/how-to-display-the-expiration-time-of-django-cookie)

Comment: @MaximilianPeters not really. The solution there does not solve my problem.

Comment: what do you get the answer from the question above?

Comment: request.META['HTTP_COOKIE'] gives me the values of the cookies.  I dont really understand what is cookie.SimpleCookie.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the expiration date is not saved in the request. The browser saves this information.